# Helper name for a route that includes an id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following route:

```
get 'institutes/:institute_id/classrooms'        => 'classrooms#index'
```

What would the name of the helper path associated with this route?

How would I use this helper path in the following View?

```
<li><%= link_to "Classrooms", helper_path %></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the auto-generated name by running `rake routes` and checking the output. You can also assign a custom name by using `as`.

```
get 'institutes/:institute_id/classrooms' => 'classrooms#index', as: 'my_route'
my_route_path(institute_id: 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. "rake routes" does not mention prefixes for custom routes. Please let me know how I can use "my_route_path" above in a View.

Comment: I explained how to use it in the second line of my example. Please read my code.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Thanks!